# Iterate over an array

Tags: loops

Let us assume this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\printlist[1]{
  Loop to get each element \el and its index \ind from {#1}{
    \ind. \el\\
  }
}
\begin{document}
\printlist{A, B, C}
\end{document}
```

It would give the output

[image]

How to implement the loop to get each element and its index from the array `{#1}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using a `\foreach`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\printlist}[1]{%
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {#1} {\xi. \x\par}%
}
\begin{document}
    \printlist{A, B, C}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I know is to use `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printlist}{m}
 {
  \begin{enumerate}
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \item ##1 }
  \end{enumerate}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printlist{A,B,C}

\end{document}
```

The function `\clist_map_inline:nn` takes each (comma separated) item from its first argument and passes it as `#1` for processing as specified in the second argument. Here the `#` has to be doubled in the second argument, so we need `##1`, because we're using it in a definition.

Comment: That did not give the OP the index of the item as well.

Comment: @daleif I based the answer on the expected output; I think it's the usual XY type of question.

Comment: `#1` in `\clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }` indicates the argument of `\printlist`?

Comment: @daleif, this is not an XY question. An answer about iteration is never complete without a coverage on how to get the iteration index.

Comment: @Viesturs you should tag egreg not me

Comment: @Viesturs I don't understand: don't you get the output you want with my code? What should be the iteration index used for?

Comment: @egreg I make up a very simple MWE to identify building blocks for a more sophisticated code.